# Ticket name with counter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make an ticket system with an counter in the channel name, but I can't find the codes to add the data into an .json file. I have currently this as codes:

```
const counter = 0;
var reached1000 = false;

if (reached1000 === true && counter !== 0) {
  counter -= 1;
} else {
  counter += 1;
}

if (counter === 1000) {
  reached1000 = true;
} else if (counter === 0) {
  reached1000 = false;
}

var counterName;

if (counter <= 10) {
  counterName = `#000${counter}`
} else if (counter <= 100) {
  counterName = `#00${counter}`
} else if (counter <= 1000) {
  counterName = `#0${counter}`
} else {
  counterName = `#${counter}`
}

bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {

  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

  if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {

    reaction.users.remove(user);
    reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${counterName}`, {
```

Comment: What does the data you want to save as a JSON look like?

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple ticket system, to write the data to a json file, you need to import fs (filesystem) and maybe json too, to turn your data into a json string using JSON.stringify(data).

Having the ticket system as a class should make it a lot easier to manage the stuff related to the ticket system.

For the counter, I made the number into a string and got its length. Then I just made a for loop going backwards from 4. This is a simpler way of making the  ticker number (#1234) simpler to make, without having to compare the counter to 1000.

Any questions just ask in the comment section.

```js
// commented out because cant be used on the browser.
// const fs = require('fs'); // for writing the JSON file

class TicketSystem {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.tickets = []; // the random data you want ot make into json.
  }

  newTicket({
    subject,
    user
  }) {
    this.counter += 1;

    // do stuff with the ticket.
    this.tickets.push({
      id: this.getCounter(),
      subject,
      user
    });
  }

  getCounter() {
    const len = `${this.counter}`.length;
    const num = [];
    num.push(this.counter);

    for (let i = 4; i > len; i--) {
      num.unshift(0);
    }
    return num.join("");
  }

  toJSON() {
    // add your own object which you want to turn into json.
    return JSON.stringify(this.tickets);
  }
}

const ticket = new TicketSystem();

// adding data to tickets
ticket.newTicket({
  subject: "Button not working",
  user: "Tom#1234"
});

ticket.newTicket({
  subject: "How do I make an invite?",
  user: "Johnny#1879"
});

const fileName = "ticket-#" + ticket.getCounter();
const jsonData = ticket.toJSON();
console.log(fileName);
console.log(jsonData);
// fs.writeFileSync(`${fileName}.json`, jsonData);
```

Comment: Hey but works this still if I put it in an ticket system with reactions? And is the number counting from #0001 to #1000 of on an other way?

Comment: What do you mean with reactions?

As for the ticket number, it works for all numbers, however if the number is under four digits, it adds zeros to the start of it to make it 4 characters long.

Comment: I have an ticket system with reactions, so if somebody want to open an ticket he needs to add an reaction on an message.